# Inserting An iframe into a DIV

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to insert a iframe into a DIV box for my layout but having trouble...I tried looking it up but still having slight issues and the rest of the 'help' involves javascript which I really want to avoid.

Problem is here ---> [http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/index.html]

```css
body{

background-color: #B5BEC6
}

#header{
width: 1000%;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: #C7DBE6;
border-bottom-style: dashed;
border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom-width: 1px;

}

#Nixie{
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
left: 225px;
top: 15px;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 26px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.nixiesbox{
width: 500px;
height: 350px;
position: absolute;
left: 35px;
top: 70px;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/stylesheet.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"><div id="Nixie">Nixie Moon</div></div>
<div class="nixiesbox">
<div style="position:absolute; left:77; top:77; width:500; height:350; border-style: none;background:#;">

 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="377" height="377" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" style="border-width:2px; border-color:#333; background:#FFF; border-style:solid;">
 </iframe>

</div> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you stuck with the overlapping or there is another issue??

Comment: "having slight issues" — What are those issues?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be noticeable I was having issues with changing the size and removing the border but Yann answer helped, thank you guys though!

Answer (score 0):

This part :

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:77; top:77; width:500; height:350; border-style: none;background:#;">
```

can be deleted.

Then you must add in your style.css a width of 100% and a height of 100% to the iframe, so that it fits to the parent container size :

```
iframe {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

If your really want to keep the style you put in the div I copied at the top, you may add it to the .nixiesbox, but honestly after deleting it, the page was the same, I then deducted that it wasn't necessary.

---

The full HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Writing/SLITD/stylesheet.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"><div id="Nixie">Nixie Moon</div></div>
<div class="nixiesbox">
<div style="background:#fff;">

 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" style="border-width:2px; border-color:#333; background:#FFF; border-style:solid;">
 </iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the full CSS :

```
body{

background-color: #B5BEC6
}

#header{
width: 1000%;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: #C7DBE6;
border-bottom-style: dashed;
border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom-width: 1px;

}

#Nixie{
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
left: 225px;
top: 15px;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 26px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.nixiesbox{
width: 500px;
height: 350px;
position: absolute;
left: 35px;
top: 70px;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.5;
}

iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see now where I went wrong and what I have to do ^_^